# Select union table from same table based on key with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I need your help. I want to `union` data from the same table based on a second table with oracle SQL.

**Table 1**

```
id | au_id | data
------------------
1  | 33    | foo
2  | 44    | foo
3  | 34    | foo
4  | 55    | foobar
5  | 55    | fooo
```

**Table 2**

```
au_id | follow_au_id
-----------------------
33    | 55
```

**Result**

```
au_id | data
----------------
33    | foo
33    | foobar
33    | fooo
44    | foo
34    | foo
55    | foobar
55    | fooo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select au_id, data from tbl
union all
select t2.au_id, t1.data from tbl t1 join tbl t2 on t1.au_id = t2.follow_au_id
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7ec43/14)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a `join`

```
select t1.au_id, t3.data 
from table1 t1 
  join table2 t2 on t1.au_id=t2.au_id 
  join table1 t3 on t2.follow_au_id = t3.au_id
union     
select t1.au_id, t1.data 
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a **JOIN** and a **UNION**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
  ( SELECT t1.au_id, t1.data FROM table1 t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.au_id,
    t1.data
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.au_id = t2.follow_au_id
  ) t
ORDER BY t.au_id
/
```

Thanks to @notulysses for pointing out, this was an incorrect solution with outer join. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7ec43/1).

Correct solution is as follows:

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Table1
  2      (id int, au_id int, data varchar2(6))
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO Table1 (id, au_id, data)
  3           VALUES (1, 33, 'foo')
  4      INTO Table1 (id, au_id, data)
  5           VALUES (2, 44, 'foo')
  6      INTO Table1 (id, au_id, data)
  7           VALUES (3, 34, 'foo')
  8      INTO Table1 (id, au_id, data)
  9           VALUES (4, 55, 'foobar')
 10      INTO Table1 (id, au_id, data)
 11           VALUES (5, 55, 'fooo')
 12  SELECT * FROM dual
 13  ;

5 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE Table2
  2      (au_id int, follow_au_id int)
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO Table2 (au_id, follow_au_id)
  3           VALUES (33, 55)
  4  SELECT * FROM dual
  5  ;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT t.*
  2  FROM
  3    ( SELECT t1.au_id, t1.data FROM table1 t1
  4    UNION ALL
  5    SELECT t2.au_id,
  6      t1.data
  7    FROM table1 t1
  8    JOIN table2 t2
  9    ON t1.au_id = t2.follow_au_id
 10    ) t
 11  ORDER BY t.au_id
 12  /

     AU_ID DATA
---------- ------
        33 foobar
        33 fooo
        33 foo
        34 foo
        44 foo
        55 fooo
        55 foobar

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually, your query is wrong – at least count the rows.